# Python : error in working on xml file

Tags: python, xml, load, openpyxl

```
import openpyxl
import os
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('data.xlsx' )
```

The above three lines code I have written to load the XML file. I am getting the below error:

```
*****Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\gprasad8\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\packaging\workbook.py", line 92
    warn(msg)
UserWarning: File contains an invalid specification for Sheet1. This will be removed*****
```

The XML file location is same as with the python file path.
Can any one help me out with this error?

Comment: Are you able to open the ".xls* file from elsewhere? Seems it's corrupted , or containing some features that (your version of) *openpyxl* doesn't know about. Anyway, hard to tell without the file.

Comment: Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62800822/openpyxl-cannot-read-strict-open-xml-spreadsheet-format-userwarning-file-conta

Answer (score 0):

Might be this error happens when openpyxl cannot understand/read an extension (source).

[build in extentions](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/src/59d472f008dbbe2f99c487879709204115090e93/openpyxl/xml/constants.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#constants.py-103:113)

Answer (score -1):

Suggest you to work with pandas library.

[Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)