# Pandas: ValueError: Worksheet index 0 is invalid, 0 worksheets found

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Simple problem that has me completely dumbfounded. I am trying to read an Excel document with pandas but I am stuck with this error:

> ValueError: Worksheet index 0 is invalid, 0 worksheets found

My code snippet works well for all but one Excel document linked below. Is this an issue with my Excel document (which definitely has sheets when I open it in Excel) or am I missing something completely obvious?

[Excel Document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nKX9kYzTlh2a-MhzveMZ2V3OzfCI0w73/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=104601276623209492420&rtpof=true&sd=true)

EDIT - Forgot the code. It is quite simply:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(FOLDER + 'omx30.xlsx')
```

`FOLDER` Is the absolute path to the folder in which the file is located.

Comment: Your link also doesn't open the document, so maybe there is something wrong with it after all. Also, make sure to include the code in the question.

Comment: @gshpychka - Yes it does. You probably don't have access to Google sheets on your machine.

Comment: @OP - Are you reading directly from the drive link or have you downloaded the Excel and tried to read it. Either way, could you please include the code you used?

Comment: Very interesting, @not_speshal do you mind telling me what you see when you follow the link?

Comment: @not_speshal I most definitely do. Google sheets says there's a problem with the file.

Comment: I see an Excel file (called omx30.xslx) with 2 worksheets: cleaned and raw. Opens fine for me. You can't "Preview" the file. But on download, it looks fine.

Comment: Yup, that's what I was referring to - Google sheets can't render the file, you have to download it.

Comment: I have the file downloaded on my machine

Comment: Yeah, google sheets is claiming there is an issue with my file and thus it cannot load in comments (there shouldn't be any though).

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp Yes it does, this exact code works for many other excel files (with different names though).

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62800822/openpyxl-cannot-read-strict-open-xml-spreadsheet-format-userwarning-file-conta address your issue?

Comment: There's definitely some issue with your Excel file. I can't read it with `pandas.read_excel` either. One workaround was to save the "cleaned" worksheet as a .csv and read that using `pd.read_csv` instead.

Comment: Reading as a .csv works for me as well so for now I will just stick to that. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there indeed is a problem with my excel file. We have not been able to figure out what though. For now the path of least resistance is simply saving as a .csv in excel and using `pd.read_csv` to read this instead.

Answer (score 38):

Your file is saved as `Strict Open XML Spreadsheet (*.xlsx)`. Because it shares the same extension as `Excel Workbook`, it isn't obvious that the format is different. Open the file in Excel and `Save As`. If the selected option is `Strict Open XML Spreadsheet (*.xlsx)`, change it to `Excel Workbook (*.xlsx)`, save it and try loading it again with pandas.

Answer (score 1):

*EDIT*: with the info that you have the original `.csv`, re-do your cleaning and save it as a `.csv` from Excel; or, if you prefer, `pd.read_csv` the original, and do your cleaning from the CLI with `pandas` directly.

Comment: I originally downloaded the file as a .csv, did some simple cleaning in Excel and then saved it as a .xlsx so unfortunately not. This doesn't solve the issue either.

Comment: If you have it as a `.csv` initially, do your cleaning in a terminal with `pandas` and then save it as a `.xlsx` with `df.to_excel`, if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe your excel delete the first sheet of index 0, and now the actual index is > 0, but the param sheet_name of function pd.read_excel is 0, so the error raised.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I converted the csv file to an xlsx file at the beginning, and the name of the worksheet below became the same as the file name when I opened it. I changed it to "Sheet1", and then opened it without reporting an error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).