# Loading SAS-produced Excel file with read_excel

Tags: python, pandas, sas, openpyxl

I have been getting the error below when trying to load an xlsx workbook produced by SAS into Python:

> **ValueError**: Unable to read workbook: could not read properties from [FILE PATH]. This is most probably because the workbook source files contain some invalid XML. Please see the exception for more details.

I tried these lines of code with no success:

```
test = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path,data_only=True)

test2 = pd.read_excel(file_path, engine='openpyxl')
```

I know the file path is correct, and based on some googling, it seems the reason the file cannot be opened by Python is because instead of being an Excel Workbook xlsx, the file is Strictly Open xlsx. If I manually resave the file as Excel Workbook xlsx, I have no issue. However, this project will be using many files saved this same way, so I want to avoid manual solutions as much as possible.

Comment: What is a "strictly open xlsx"? `xlsx` is the well know extension of Excel files, which follows a specific standard. If Excel can't open the file, it's a bad file. If the project generates such files, the file generation code must be fixed

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - a [Strict Open XML spreadsheet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98nGP.png) OP: [relevant link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62800822/openpyxl-cannot-read-strict-open-xml-spreadsheet-format-userwarning-file-conta).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos from my understanding the strictly open xlsx has some legacy Excel components for compatibility. I have no issue opening/editing the files normally. And they were created by an older SAS program, which I think is the heart of the problem...

Comment: Which openpyxl version are you using? Can you upgrade it?

Comment: Can you share an example SAS program that produces an XSLX file that the read_excel() function cannot handle?

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar though not identical problem with hundreds of excel files saved with the xlsx extension that could not be opened by openpyxl (or pandas) due to an old file format (cannot remember exact details). I solved it with a function utilising xlwings library. Probably only works on windows. I'm not 100% sure this will solve your particular problem but I would expect it too since its the equivalent of resaving manually. Here comes the code:

```
import pathlib
import xlwings as xw
from collections.abc import Iterable


def resave_excel_files(file_paths: Iterable[pathlib.Path]):
    allowed_suffixes = {".xlsx", ".xlsm"}

    with xw.App(visible=False) as app:

        for path in file_paths:

            if not (path.is_file() and (path.suffix in allowed_suffixes)):
                print(f"{path} is not a valid excel-file path, skipping!")
                continue

            try:
                wb = app.books.open(path)
                wb.save(path)
                wb.close()
                print("Resaved: ", path.name)
            except Exception as err:
                print(f"\nCOULDN'T RESAVE {path.name} ERROR INFO:")
                print(f"{err}, {type(err)}\n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    dir_path = pathlib.Path("path/to/relevant/dir")
    paths = [ path for path in dir_path.iterdir() if path.is_file() ]
    resave_excel_files(paths)
```

I hope this helps you!